# Cron job "connection refused"

Tags: cron, network-programming, connection

I have a daily cron job which is supposed to restart a server (which listens on port 8443) at 4am if a configuration file has been updated. The command it executes works successfully if executed from the command line. When run as a cron job, it shuts down the server successfully but then fails to restart it, reporting a "connection refused" error:

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
```

To try and track this down, I edited crontab to run the job one minute in the future. There is nothing reported in /var/log/syslog:

```
Jul  5 10:31:39 foo crontab[20375]: (user) END EDIT (user)
Jul  5 10:33:01 foo cron[535]: (user) RELOAD (crontabs/user)
Jul  5 10:33:01 foo CRON[20381]: (user) CMD ($HOME/my-server restart >>$HOME/my-server.log)
```

I have a chain containing a REJECT rule in iptables, but it also has a LOG rule which logs all rejections, so that doesn't look like what's causing this.

Does anyone have any ideas?